# Crossfilter.js group() behavior in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a demo app that uses crossfilter.js dimensions and groups to power graphs with interactive filters (very similar to the Airline on-time demo http://square.github.io/crossfilter/). My real dataset is far too large to use crossfilter.js. I have had success using pandas to apply similar filtering to the data, though.

I am having trouble making the jump, however, to understanding how to model/represent crossfilter's group() behavior in pandas - namely

> a grouping intersects the crossfilter's current filters, except for the associated dimension's filter.
>   https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group-map-reduce

For example, using vehicle data:

```
Make   Year   Color
-------------------
Ford   2000   Red
Honda  2001   Blue
Ford   2001   Green
```

If I applied the filter `Make: Ford` and got counts for each dimension/group, I'd expect:

```
Make:
  Ford: 2
  Honda: 1
Year:
  2000: 1
  2001: 1
Color:
  Red: 1
  Blue: 0
  Green: 1
```

So, for the `Make` dimension, the `Make: Ford` filter is dropped to get the counts. For the `Year` and `Color` dimensions, it is applied, so the 2001 Blue Honda doesn't contribute to the counts.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a good answer, this is what I've cobbled together. It requires encoding the filters into a tree so that it can be walked and the appropriate series filters nullified in each pass. I'm still interested in better solutions though.

Example call based on the above question, where `df` is the pandas dataframe:

```
crossfilter(df, ('eq', 'Make', 'Ford'), ['Make', 'Year', 'Color'])
```

The code:

```
# filter operators of the form (operator, filter1, filter2)
group_ops = {
    'and': operator.and_,
    'or': operator.or_,
}

# hokie way of forcing all-pass or all-fail filters
nan = float('nan')


# recursive function that turns a tree of python-dict encoded filters into
# bitwise operators for pandas
def build_filter(df, payload, nullify_series=None, nullify_value=True):
    if not payload:
        # no filters, but we have to return something
        # so grab the first series and filter out all NaN values
        return operator.ne(df.ix[:,0], nan)
    op = payload[0]
    if op in value_ops:
        # format: (operator, series, val)
        series = payload[1]
        value = payload[2]
        if series == nullify_series:
            # nullify filter
            if nullify_value:
                # push toward True (e.g. nested in an 'and' operator)
                return operator.ne(df[series], nan)
            else:
                # push toward False (e.g. nested in an 'or' operator)
                return operator.eq(df[series], nan)
        return value_ops[op](df[series], value)
    elif op == 'not':
        # format: ('not', nested_filter)
        value = payload[1]
        return operator.inv(build_filter(df, value, nullify_series, False))
    else:
        # format: (operator, nested_filter_1, nested_filter_2)
        group1 = payload[1]
        group2 = payload[2]
        return group_ops[op](build_filter(df, group1, nullify_series, True),
                             build_filter(df, group2, nullify_series, True))

# returns value counts for all series in `gather`, applying filters in `filters` in all other series
def crossfilter(df, filters, gather):
    df_scoped = df[gather]
    results = { series: df_filtered[series].value_counts().to_dict()
                for series in gather
                for df_filtered in [ df_scoped[build_filter(df_scoped, filters, series)]
                                     if filters else df_scoped ]}
    return results
```